# knockout, 2 similar lists on same page

Tags: list, data-binding, knockout.js, model

I want to applybindings on 2 lists using knockout.js. 
The problem is that these 2 lists have similar fields and names sometimes are same.
Every list has a form to add some fields. I dont know how to separate these lists and add new line to correct one after using concrete form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I do it is with a complex viewModel like this:

```
var list1Model = {
    name: ko.observable(),
    type: ko.observable(),
};

var list2Model = {
    name: ko.observable(),
    type: ko.observable(),
};

var viewModel = {
list1: list1Model,
list2: list2Model
}
```

Then when you use it in your HTML:

```
    <div data-bind="with: list1">
        <div data-bind="text: name">

        </div>
        <div data-bind="text: type">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="with: list2">
        <div data-bind="text: name">

        </div>
        <div data-bind="text: type">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I also found a solution with applyBindings to DOM element  

`ko.applyBindings(viewModel.list1Model, $('#List1')[0]);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel.list2Model, $('#List2')[0]);`

Comment: yes that's better if you need to be very specific and want to use that model only on that element